# Google Apps Script - setValue() suddenly stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first question, I looked around and didn't find the answer to my problem. I'm sorry if I miss a detail.

I have a little script for "creating" a new file from a template every time you manually run the script added in the Menu with ui.createMenu.

It has been working without any problem for a few month and last week it stopped working. I debugged it and it always gets stuck at the lines with getValue() or setValue(). I've tried with changing the type from a1 string to number, to setValue() to setFormula().

The code always worked by demanding in a1 notation the cell containing the title of the Recipe, getting it with getValue(), then automatically creates a copy of a template changing the title to the content of the aforementioned cell. After, it opens the file and copies it's URL in a cell dedicated to that with setValue() in the original file.

The layout is:

Column B contains the titles of the recipes
Column E contains the URL to the dedicated files of each recipe

```
function IDcreator()
{
 //Prompt
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Liste des recettes');
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var result = ui.prompt('To create a new ID Recette, please...','Enter the cell with the title with the format a1' , ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

//User's respons
var button = result.getSelectedButton();
var title = result.getResponseText();

if (button == ui.Button.OK)
{  
 var titleAuxRange = sheet.getRange(title);
 var titleAux = titleAuxRange.getValue();

 var fileID = '1huAX42bwp8jMJ8GQSW2FWM_KWnbBSnzH1zClKbaH8FY';

 var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).makeCopy(titleAux);

 var newURL = file.getUrl();
 var html = "<script>window.open('"+newURL+"');</script>";
 var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open new ID'); 
 //Force new tab to open

 var auxCol = sheet.getRange(title).getColumn();
 var auxRow = sheet.getRange(title).getRow();
 auxCol += 3;

 sheet.getRange(auxRow,auxCol).setValue(newURL);
}

else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL)
{ui.alert('Création de nouvelle ID Recette annulée');}
else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE)
{ui.alert('Création de nouvelle ID Recette annulée');}
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated since I'm doing it manually right now and it's a waste of time...

Regards,

Agustin

UPDATE:

- Error in the Apps Script:
  IDcreator   Script autonome 5 sept. 2018 à 17:21:27 1236.855 s  Échec
- getLastColumn and getLastRow also stopped working all over the file.
- While using the native function of "importRange" in other file with the URL of the file with the Recipes, the function doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome. Please checkout the execution transcript and [edit] your question to add the error message that you get.

Comment: Based on what you have mentioned about it getting stuck on get value. I would recommend doubling checking the your IDs and Sheet Names. Especially if it is saying something like "Cannot get range of null".

Comment: @Rubén, I only get the timeout error after the 5 minutes of the script getting stuck at getValue or setValue.

Comment: @New_2_Code already checked that and nop, it's not the problem.

Also, I noticed that when it starts to happen, the Google Sheets function "importRange" stops working if I use that files URL.